# Is this a correct example of Higher Order Component?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I recently went through the docs of Higher Order Components and got a bit confused about the implementation. I want to create a loader component which wraps up the logic and shows only if the data has been loaded and displays loading screen otherwise. Is this the correct way of implementing it Can anyone suggest improvements?

WithLoader.js (HOC file)

```
export const WithLoader = ( props ) => {
    if(props.showLoader === true) 
    {
        return (
           <h1>Loading...</h1>
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return props.children;
    }
}
```

index.js

```
//pass true/false in showLoader prop if data is received
<WithLoader showLoader={true}>
           //Assume that SummaryComponent displays a list of items
           <SummaryComponent cartItems={cartItems} />
        </WithLoader>
```

Answer (score 0):

> According to the definition of [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), a higher-order component(HOC) is a function that takes a component and returns a new component.

so, withLoader function should take a component and then return a component that contains the logic you want to implement,

```
const withLoader = component => {
   let C = component;
   return function Component({ showLoader, ...rest }) {
   if (showLoader === true) {
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
   } else {
      return <C {...rest} />;
}};};
```

then, create the enhancedComponent using hoc function,

```
const WithLoader = withLoader(SummaryComponent);
```

finally, use it,

```
<WithLoader showLoader={true} />;
```

check it demo in [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-ganguly-56d86)

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://www.programmerfirst.com/2018/10/higher-order-components-basics.html) you go and read about basics Higher Order Components

Comment: I wouldn't characterize an answer which provides just a link to a third party site without summarizing the contents as a good answer. Would you be so kind to either sum it up or at least clarify why the linked source is a better alternative to the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)?